# How to click a link on a web page using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a link on a web page with Python Selenium but I am getting this exception:

> no such element: Unable to locate element:

I have already tried using `find_element_by_xpath`, `find_element_by_partial_link_text` and `find_element_by_link_text`.

This is my code:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/me/Downloads/projetos/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

driver.get('http://10.7.0.4/web/guest/br/websys/webArch/mainFrame.cgi');

time.sleep(10) # Let the user actually see something!
#elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="machine"]/div[1]/div[1]/dl[2]/dt/a')
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Mensagens (2item(ns))')

elem.click()
print("Fim...")
```

This is the element I need to click:

```html
<a href="javascript:wsMenu_jumpUrl('../../websys/webArch/getStatus.cgi#linkStateMsg');" class="">Mensagens (2item(ns))</a>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `explicit waits` and with the `customized css` :

**CSS_SELECTOR :**

```
a[href*='../../websys/webArch/getStatus.cgi']
```

**Sample code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='../../websys/webArch/getStatus.cgi']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'ebsys/webArch/getStatus.cgi') and contains(text(), 'Mensagens')]"))).click()
```

Comment: the console gime this
"raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"

Comment: Can we have page resource as well ? Or page url if it's public ?

Comment: How can I post source code page here? I mean, is it against forum rules?
The code is large, 12.000 characters

Comment: You need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: try this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I8wg78YnJd1NMQWwppSGchcFZWYTHweq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @marreco : Can you try with update 1 code [see above].

Comment: when I try look at happens ...,
"File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "

Comment: and what does this return `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'ebsys/webArch/getStatus.cgi') and contains(text(), 'Mensagens')]").click()` ?

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, I try your suggestion:
"raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@href, 'websys/webArch/getStatus.cgi') and contains(text(), 'Mensagens')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)"

Comment: It could be cause of iframe as well, Can you look if it's inside an iframe ?